# handling BC dates in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm planning to make an application that needs to store dates way before 1970. Maybe even BC dates. Do you think I should store and handle that manually or can I use the Date/Time classes in Rails or use some plugin?

Thanks,

Tam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1970 won't present a problem, nor will BC.

```
>> Date.today - 3000.years
=> Mon, 27 Dec -0991
```

Is there something more specific that you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks...thought that it wouldn't be stored in MySql but it did :)